# access cgi script from a subdomain with nicer URL

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi, virtualhost, cgi-bin

I want to access this page (working)

http://stats.example.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?config=www.example.com

via

http://stats.example.com/?config=www.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName stats.example.com
        DocumentRoot /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        DirectoryIndex awstats.pl
</VirtualHost>
```

however this triggers the download of awstats.pl, obviously not my intention. How can I make this work, or is there a concept I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient that the script be in a directory called "cgi-bin" on the filesystem; it must be using the `cgi-script` handler. Use a `SetHandler` directive to set the handler within a `<Files>` section to restrict it to the appropriate filenames.